# how to give permissions to the user custom actions( site action)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

i had written code using server side object model for adding user custom actions to the site action..now my question is how to give permission levels to that action because every one see custom actions create when it is added in site action menu.i have to restrict using user custom actions from site action.How can i do this using server object model.

Answer (score 0):

The customAction tag in Element.xml file has Rights attribute you can use that to give permissions

```
<CustomAction Rights = "Text"> </CustomAction>
```

Rights: Optional Text. Specifies a set of rights that the user must have for the link to be visible, for example, "ViewListItems,ManageAlerts". If it is not specified, the action always appears in the list of actions. To specify multiple rights, separate the values by using commas. The set of rights are grouped logically according to AND logic, which means that a user must have all the specified rights to see an action. For a list of possible values, see Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBasePermissions.

Comment: Thanq very much for giving reply to me.i have question, there is any restriction for site action name length..when i added lengthy name to site action..it will be expanded and not looking good settings menu.